# HttpTransportSE requestDump gives NullPointerException

Tags: android, ksoap2, ksoap, httptransportse

I'm trying to access a `webservice` in Android via `Ksoap2` for Android.

The `SoapObject` is created OK, the S.O.P of the `bodyOut` outputs the desired strings. But when I do a `requestDump` of the `HttpTransportSE` object I create to make the call, a `NullPointerException` happens. In other words, the transport object is null. How can this happen?

Web Service is at http://srilanka.lk:9080/services/CropServiceProxy?wsdl

**This service works very well with SoapUI.**

**SoapUI Request:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:v1="http://schemas.icta.lk/xsd/crop/handler/v1/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <v1:getCropDataList>
         <v1:code>ABK</v1:code>
      </v1:getCropDataList>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**SoapUI Response:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:getCropDataListResponse xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.icta.lk/xsd/crop/handler/v1/">
         <ns1:cropInfo>
            <ns1:name>Ambul Kesel</ns1:name>
            <ns1:price>35.0</ns1:price>
            <ns1:location>Dambulla</ns1:location>
         </ns1:cropInfo>
         <ns1:cropInfo>
            <ns1:name>Ambul Kesel</ns1:name>
            <ns1:price>40.0</ns1:price>
            <ns1:location>Dambulla</ns1:location>
         </ns1:cropInfo>
      </ns1:getCropDataListResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Client Side Complex Type `KvmSerializable` implementation:**

```
public class CropInfo implements KvmSerializable {

 private String name;
 private float price;
 private String location;

 @Override
 public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
  switch (arg0){
  case 0:
   return name;
  case 1:
   return price;
  case 2:
   return location;
  default:
    return null;
  }
 }

 @Override
 public int getPropertyCount() {
  return 3;
 }

 @Override
 public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo arg2) {
  switch (arg0){
  case 0:
   arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
   arg2.name = "Name";
   break;
  case 1:
   arg2.type = Float.class;
   arg2.name = "Price";
   break;
  case 2:
   arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
   arg2.name = "Location";
   break;
  default:
    break;
  }

 }

 @Override
 public void setProperty(int arg0, Object arg1) {
  switch(arg0){
  case 0:
   name = arg1.toString();
   break;
  case 1:
   price = Float.parseFloat(arg1.toString());
  case 2:
   location = arg1.toString();
  default:
   break;
  }
 }
}
```

**Web Service Call:**

```
public void btnOnClick(View v){
     String NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.icta.lk/xsd/crop/handler/v1/";
  String URL = "http://220.247.225.202:9080/services/CropServiceProxy.CropServiceProxyHttpSoap12Endpoint";

  String method_name = "getCropDataList";
  String SOAP_ACTION = "http://schemas.icta.lk/xsd/crop/handler/v1/getCropDataList";

  SoapObject soap_request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, method_name);
  soap_request.addProperty("code", "ABK" );

  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
  envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soap_request);
  envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "cropInfo", CropInfo.class);
  //envelope.dotNet=true;

  Marshal floatMarshal = new MarshalFloat();
  floatMarshal.register(envelope);

  System.out.println("body out : " + envelope.bodyOut.toString());

  //AndroidHttpTransport http_transport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
  HttpTransportSE http_transport  = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
  try {
                    //NullPointerException HERE
   System.out.println(http_transport.requestDump);
   http_transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

   //because we should expect a vector, two kinds of prices are given
   Vector<CropInfo> result_array = (Vector<CropInfo>)envelope.getResponse();
   if(result_array != null){
    for (CropInfo current_crop: result_array){
     System.out.println(current_crop.getName());
     System.out.println(Float.toString(current_crop.getPrice()));
    }
   }

  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   answer.setText("error caught");
   //System.out.println(http_transport.responseDump);
  }

  // String result_string[] = (String[])result;

  //answer.setText("returned");

    }
```

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the [`debug`](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/doc/api/org/ksoap2/transport/Transport.html#debug) field of the `Transport` instance to `true`, then call the `call(String,SoapEnvelope)` method in order for the `requestDump` field to be set:

```
  HttpTransportSE http_transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
  http_transport.debug = true;
  try {
   http_transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
   System.out.println(http_transport.requestDump);
  //...
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I've gotten the order wrong. Made the corrections you suggested and I get a XMLPullParser Error now at the call method. I'm struggling with that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557180/ksoap2-for-android-gives .

Comment: @Daniel dude I love you from the **bottom of my heart**  _where_ do you get info about these small things from??! I asked a different [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11048426/1434372), the answer to which led me to a problem @chamila was having , even the answerer forgot to mention that small line regarding setting `httpTransport.debug=true;` ... wow I was stuck at that for **2 Hours** **Two** I'm really happy right now. Pardon my _long_ comment. Again **Thanks** !!