# Expecting Nested XML structure but receiving SOAP structure

Tags: android, xml, soap, xml-serialization, ksoap2

I'm making an app that is requesting data from a Web Service (implementing Soap).

**People who are viewing this pleaase post doubts in comments... I havent got any response to the question do ask me if there is any doubts, i really need help, am stuck!!**

So to make request I have to use ksoap libraries.. the Web service is **coded to return a response of type XML**. When the web service itself is tested on a browser it displays a result which is as follows:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <SOBKeyList>
- <Key>
  <value>12686</value> 
  </Key>
- <Key>
  <value>16238</value> 
  </Key>
- <Key>
  <value>26978</value> 
  </Key>
  </SOBKeyList>
```

clearly an **XML** file...

`However` when i use ths code to get a result:

```
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String xml = null;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();

    pi.setName("fkey");
    pi.setValue(0);
    pi.setType(Integer.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    pi = new PropertyInfo();

    pi.setName("tkey");
    pi.setValue(999999);
    pi.setType(Integer.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);


    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
    Object response = null; 

    try {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        response = envelope.getResponse();
        xml = response.toString();
        Log.d("xml:", xml);
    } catch (SoapFault e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("Soap Fault", e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("IOexception", e.toString());
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("XmlPullParserException", e.toString());
    }

    return xml;
}
```

It returns a **nested SOAP structure** *confirmed* by the Log entry which i make ( `Log.d("xml:", xml);` )
The corresponding LogCat entry is: (i've formatted it to make it the SOAP structure's heirarchy apparent... )

```
anyType{
      SOBKeyList=anyType{
                          Key=anyType{value=12686 ; };
                          Key=anyType{value=16238 ; };
                          Key=anyType{value=26978 ; };
                         };
          }
```

The reason why i necessarily need an XML is because later I parse the string to get a **DOM** element and when the above string is passed it returns the following:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT anyType{SOBKeyLi...@1:119 in java.io.StringReader@40ec9c68)

also from there onward my entire code depends on the fact that the response was **XML**.

**Explaination of the reason why i expected an XML** :
Now you may asked why I coded my app expecting XML when i had not tested the Web service the reason is: The Web service was coded my a third party who assured me of an XML response , now i dont have enough time to change my remaining code to exploit a SOAP structure !! 
-_-
I'm in a fix. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String responseXML = httpTransport.responseDump;
```

- `HttpTransportSE.responseDump` gives you response in XML format.
- `HttpTransportSE.requestDump` gives you request in XML format.

However to be able to change and retrieve any of these values you must set the `debug` field of `HttpTransportSE` to `true`
so your code should look like...

```
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
    httpTransport.debug =true;      
    try {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);          
        xml = httpTransport.responseDump;
        Log.d("xml:", "is:" + xml);     
    }
```

Also you can parse your response like as follow:

```
ArrayList<String> listValues = new ArrayList<String>();

            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            SoapObject soapSOBKeyList = (SoapObject) response.getProperty("SOBKeyList");

            int keyCount = soapSOBKeyList.getPropertyCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < keyCount; i++) {
                String value = soapSOBKeyList.getPropertyAsString(i);
                listValues.add(value);
            }

            return listValues;
```

Comment: I just realized I'd posted some wrong piece of code (I edited in the question as well): 

`HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
    Object response = null; 

    try {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        response = envelope.getResponse();
        xml = response.toString();
        Log.d("xml:", xml);
    }`

Comment: I'm already using HttpTransportSE ... where should i put the line `httpTransport.responseDump` ??

Comment: `httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);`
`xml = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;`

Comment: Now i edited my answer. You can parse your non-XML :) response.

Comment: `httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
   xml = httpTransport.responseDump;
   Log.d("xml:", "is:" + xml);
   //response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
   
   //xml = response.toString();`

Comment: this is how i changed my code... ^^^ but the `xml = httpTransport.responseDump;` line stores `null` in `xml` ... the `Log.d("xml","is:"+xml);` shows up as `xml is: null` in logcat!!

Comment: As I understand the code you posted will parse the response into String array having three `Key` items... but i cannot use such a list in later code.. as I'm using an inbuilt parser that converts the xml to a DOM (Document obejct) element... i need to work with this DOM element in the later parts of my code.. thus getting a simple string in XML format is very necessary...

Comment: I got the correct answer from another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4574997/1434372) to a different question.. I'm editing your answer to **complete it**