# How to see SOAP request XML body on Java as a string?

Tags: java, xml, soap

I'm debugging an old Java Android code which makes some SOAP API calls, but I'm having a hard time looking at the request body content as a string (maybe printing it to the console) so I can replicate this request on other languages.

The java code looks something like this:

```
String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        //String URL = servidor + "";
        String URL = servidor + "";

        String METHOD_NAME = "";
        String SOAP_ACTION = "";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("key", key);
        request.addProperty("dev", dev);
        request.addProperty("mac", mac);
        request.addProperty("x", x);
        request.addProperty("y", y);
        request.addProperty("user", user);
        request.addProperty("pass", pass);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
```

I've tried printing `request` and `envelope` objects as strings but it really does not shows me what I want. I'm expecting a XML string so I can replicate in other places....

```
Log.v("Karlo",envelope.toString());
Log.v("Karlo",request.toString());
```

Comment: Which http client are you using? https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html

Comment: Not sure. All imports are coming from `org.ksoap2`

Comment: Call is made from `HttpTransportSE` object @LMC

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4574997/2834978